# I need to programatically create several variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I asked this question but it was marked as duplicate - it's not.

I need to programmatically create X number of variables (the number will be the value of someArray.length - which is also something created programmatically and thus unknown to me).

Is there any way to say "there's 8 items in this set, so I need 8 variables, and I need to be able to call on them/manipulate them later?" Hopefully I'm making sense.

My core problem: I programmatically generate a list of links. Can be any number of links. I need to be able to validate that the user clicks each of these links before advancing.

Comment: It does not make much sense: you must either use array or objects instead. But unless you explain your initial problem it would not be possible to help you solve it properly.

Comment: @Ryan, why do you think that you need those variables? why don't you just use `someArray`?

Comment: What you are describing - a collection of variables of a given length - IS an array.  Just make an array to store your states, and then check over the array to see if all of them are true or not (for bonus cool points you can use array.reduce()).  Alternately, you can add new properties to objects in your original array.

Comment: @Thomas I supposed I don't know "why". I just thought this was the way to go lol

Comment: @PMV - could you elaborate? "make an array to store your states" - how do you mean? Are you aware of an example I could take a look at?

Comment: @Ryan, It's not. Using enumerated *whatever* in your code is a sign that you're doing sth. wrong. As PVM mentioned, use an Array, or a Key-value map. That depends on your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I programmatically create variables in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834158/can-i-programmatically-create-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: no - and i've since realized through answers in this thread that that's not even what i need

Answer (score 3):

> I programmatically generate a list of links. Can be any number of links. I need to be able to validate that the user clicks each of these links before advancing.

You do not need to create an unknown number of variables  to solve your problem (how would you name them?). As stated by other commenters, you have a list of links, and you need to keep track of which ones have been clicked.

There are numerous ways to solve this problem in JavaScript. Below is an example of a straightforward approach which should be easy to follow. The approach is simply to use another array, `linksClicked`, to keep track of which links have been clicked. To validate, count the number of links that have been clicked and compare to the total number of links.

```js
var arrayOfLinks = [
  'http://www.stackoverflow.com',
  'http://www.arstechnica.com'
];

var linksClicked = [];

function clickLink(url){
  //check if link is in arrayOfLinks
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfLinks.length; i++){
    //if link is in arrayOfLinks, mark it as clicked
    if(arrayOfLinks[i] === url){
      linksClicked[i] = true;
    }
  }
}

function checkLinksClicked(){
  //count number of links that have been clicked
  var linkSum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < linksClicked.length; i++){
    if(linksClicked[i]){
      linkSum++;
    }
  }
  return linkSum;
}

console.log(checkLinksClicked());

clickLink('http://www.stackoverflow.com');

console.log(checkLinksClicked());

clickLink('http://www.stackoverflow.com');

console.log(checkLinksClicked());

clickLink('http://www.arstechnica.com');

console.log(checkLinksClicked());
```

Comment: What is actually taking in the user clicking the links?

Comment: The example code simply demonstrates an approach to the book-keeping part of your question: How to keep track of clicked links without using an unknown number of variables. To really solve your problem you would also need code that generates links, then add event handling code to capture when a link is clicked and connect this to the book-keeping code. If you edit your question to be more precise and include example code of what you have done so far, I assume you will get even better answers.